# How to add view to Entity framework Entity model?

Tags: entity-framework

When I create a view in database, then I want to add it to EF Model. In the list to add object, I can see and select the view, but nothing happened when try to add it to Model.
It is because there is no Key for the view.

How to add view to Model?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx), it might help

Alex

Comment: you've got a dead link